# Can a differentiable function be real valued at infinite points and complex valued at some other intervals

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Can a differentiable function (in real part) be real valued at an interval (infinite points) and complex valued at some other intervals?
For example Exp[it] is real valued at countable points and complex valued at other uncountable points. I am trying to understand if a a differentiable function can have both real valued and complex valued intervals (on real axis).

Comment: "Continous function", yes it can exist. "Analytic function", no it cannot. This is why you are struggling to find examples; most elementary functions are analytic.

Comment: Does $\sqrt x$ match your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. We are looking at $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ here; which can be visualised as a line in $3$-D space, where the $x$-axis is the input axis, $y$ is the real part of the output, and $z$ is the imaginary part. We simply draw a straight lines along the $z=0$ plane at some intervals, and join this to some other lines along the $y=0$ plane via more straight lines. This is still continuous as required. Other constructions can also affirm the existence of such functions even when differentiability or smoothness is required - for differentiable, simple round the joined corners in a way that preserves differentiability (for example, an arc should work). Smooth functions can also be done in this way although it is a little harder to find an explicit construction.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say differentiable instead of continuous. I have now amended the question. Could you let me know your comment for the differentiable functions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= \exp(-1/x^2)$ if $x<0$, $f(x)=\sqrt{-1}\exp(-1/x^2)$ if $x>0$, and $f(0)=0$. It is infinitely differentiable.